# Pass a parameter to global query filter

Tags: entity-framework-core

With new ef.core global query filters, is it possible to pass a dynamic parameter to it?

I want all queries to be filtered by user's company id. All models have a `companyId` value.  I know there are libraries like [this one](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters), but is there a native way to achieve it?

Comment: Create `CompanyId` **property of your context** and use it when setting the filter. EFC will use the property value from the actual context when executing queries, as explained in the [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) example and tip.

Comment: Something like     "var foo = 1;
            modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicQualification>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<int>(b, "BelongToCompanyId") == foo);" ?  it causes 'InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.'  with ef.core 2.0.1

Comment: Add `public int CompanyId { get; set; }` to your db context derived class. Then `modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicQualification>().HasQueryFilter(‌​b => EF.Property<int>(b, "BelongToCompanyId") == this.CompanyId);` should work. Just make sure to set the property before executing queries, e.g. `context.CompanyId = ...; var result = context.Set<AcademicQualification>().ToList();`